# Count different values in a column, while doing total and group by different column values

Tags: mysql

We have a table with data from different nodes and one of the column will have status report as "compliant or non-compliant", sample data as below

[image: Sample Data]

I want to filter the table in such a way that if any of the checks on a node shows non compliant, it should be flagged as non-compliant and rest as compliant. Using below query i am able to do it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_nodes, 
       SUM(fully_compliant = 0) AS Non_compliant_nodes, 
       SUM(fully_compliant = 1) AS compliant_nodes 
FROM ( 
    SELECT Node, CASE WHEN SUM(Status = 'Compliant') = COUNT(*) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS fully_compliant 
    FROM your_table GROUP BY Node 
)
```

[image: Current Output]

Now, i want to group and split the result by dept as below, how can i achieve this

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
select    dept,
          count(*) as total_nodes,
          sum(case when non_compliant_chk = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as compliant_nodes,
          sum(case when non_compliant_chk > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as non_compliant_nodes
from      (
            select    dept,
                      node,
                      sum(case when 'Non-Compliant' then 1 else 0 end) as non_compliant_chk
            from      your_table
            group by  dept,
                      node
          ) v
group by  dept;
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I am learning TSQL, can you explain what does 'v' in your query mean

Comment: It is an alias for the inline view. You could alternatively use a, b, c, xyz, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With few modifications to what Brian suggested, I am able to get the desired result

select    `dept`,
          count(*) as total_nodes,
          sum(case when non_compliant_chk = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as compliant_nodes,
          sum(case when non_compliant_chk > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as non_compliant_nodes
from      (
            select    `dept`,
                      `node`,
                       COUNT(CASE WHEN `Compliance-Status` = 'Non-Compliant' THEN 1 END) 'non_compliant_chk'
            from table WHERE DOR >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
            group by  `Dept`,
                      `Node`
          ) v
group by  `Dept`;